# How to require raw static html file on webpack

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, webpack

I have written a simple template

test.html

```
<div>raw text with content</div>
```

all I want to do is requiring the raw file, with no modifications

like

```
require('./test.html'); // should return "<div>raw text with content</div>"
```

I have tried loading the html using the extra-text-plugin, but it doesn't work

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'); 

module.exports =
{
    module:
    {
        loaders:
            [
                { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html' }
            ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].html")
    ]
};
```

Comment: Don't use Webpack as a build system - **it is not**. Webpack is a module bundler for JS and your static assets that you use **in it**.

Comment: By the way - webpack perfectly well working with gulp/grunt.

Answer (score 10):

Try to use [`html-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader):

```
 import TestTemplate from 'html!./test.html';
```

Comment: Why does it return "exports = template_content" instead of just the template content? how am I supposed to fetch the content

Comment: He did not have TestTemplate in his file!!!! Why everyone is saying import template form file.html in all answeres. There is no export in html file.

Comment: @AliKhosro because it's using html-loader.... Which basically puts your html in an export

Comment: import TestTemplate from 'html-loader!./test.html';

is current convention. There is no need for extra config.

Comment: What if I need to load HTML from within a function? Can't use `import`, need to use `require`